# OData Modeling: Master Data vs. Transactional Data

Tags: odata, modeling

We are designing our OData Restful API and there is one design decision that seems to be a bit tricky.

There is some master data in the application that can be retrieved by the user at anytime. The relevant entities are:

```
Plan -> Operation (Plan has one to many Operations)
```

When we create an order in the system (this is the transactional part), it will get assigned a Plan. The relationship looks like:

```
Order -> Plan -> Operation (Order has one Plan, Plan has one to many Operations)
```

Within an order (in the transactional part), the user may create a new Plan and Operations. So, the master data of Plan & Operations are used as 'templates', the order gets created with them but the user can change them.

**The question is: Does it make sense to separate the master data entities from transactional entities in an OData model?**

```
MasterDataPlan -> MasterDataOperation
Order -> Plan -> Operation
```

(This way, MasterData entities become read-only.)

vs.

```
Plan -> Operation
Order -> Plan -> Operation
```

I can provide more details if necessary.